# How to solve "'response' is defined but never used" on axios.then callback

Tags: axios, eslint

I'm submitting a Post request using Axios, and I want to give the user some confirmation if the request is successful.  However, I have no use for the `response` variable, so I get an `eslint` error.  How to fix this?

```
axios.post('/api/option.json', {
    choices: myChoices
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert('Form was submitted successfully')
  })
```

Error:

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'response' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/components/Options.vue:78:15
```

EDIT (April 2020): Oops, looks like this question now has 1k views but 0 upvotes. I'm guessing I wrote a tantalizing title but the question isn't helping people. Please comment if I should rename this or link to a better question?

Comment: After the `alert()`, you can add a `return response;`. I've seen returning the response or error of an axios promise many times in other people's code; even if you don't necessarily have to return anything or use the returned value - this may get rid of your error

Comment: since the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it (different from upvoting) - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 12):

'variable' is defined but never used, this error simply means the variable that you declared is not used in the program.

Solution -

In your program use response as the return value.

```
axios.post("/api/option.json", {
  choices: myChoices;
})
.then(response => {
  alert("Form was submitted successfully");
  return response
});
```

OR

```
axios.post("/api/option.json", {
  choices: myChoices;
})
.then(() => {
  alert("Form was submitted successfully");
});
```

OR

If you do not like this feature of eslint you can turn off by adding this object in package.json file.

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off",
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the best solution I found:

```
axios.post('/api/option.json', {
    choices: myChoices
  })
  .then(() => {
    alert('Form was submitted successfully')
  })
```